# React js dropdown not scrollable

Tags: css, reactjs, dropdown

I have a drop-down that shows different games, on desktop you can see the entire list but on a laptop, the list gets clipped, Tried to fix this by adding `overflow: auto` to make it scrollable but that makes the dropdown disappear. Any idea how make it scrollable?

**Images**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: add a minimal reproducible example; image won't provide enough debugging info

Comment: Please show the **essential** code to reproduce your problem. Your question  needs more details to be answered. Read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

`overflow` property works only with absolute height. `height: 100%` is relative to its parent.

```
.navbar-container .game-dropdown {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #878799;
  font-size: 1em;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Code only answers can almost always be improved by adding some explanation of how and why they work. In this case pointing out what you've changed and why would really help the answer.